# ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath() returns 0.0.0.0:8080 when app deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

i am using ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath() to build download file urls in spring boot rest app, this works fine locally but when deployed on a tomcat server on oiur company server it returns 0.0.0.0:8080 instead of the actual url

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Could it be that your company is using a proxy (e.g. NGINX or Apache) in front of Tomcat that hosts your application and the proxy is deployed on the same machine as Tomcat?

Comment: Thanks for the information, i will check with them.If they are, what should i do to get the host url to build custom urls.